# Converting dates stored as text to proper Date format (i.e. dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I convert the following text into `{dd/mm/yyyy}` format, in excel:

```
Dec 3, 2012
Nov 1, 2012
Oct 2, 2012
Sep 3, 2012
Aug 1, 2012
Jul 2, 2012
Jun 1, 2012
```

The expected results should be:-

```
3/12/2012 {dd/mm/yyyy}
1/11/2012
```

Comment: How are these values stored originally - is all the text in one cell, or is each date in one cell on its own?

Comment: Can't you just set an individuell format? Right click on cell -> cell format -> individual -> dd//mm//yyyy ? I don't know the exact english names for the menu items.

Comment: what version of excel are you using?

Comment: @AliciaGan i updated the answer

Comment: Brian Vanderbusch, maybe 2007 version

Answer (score 8):

Try using "Text to columns" functionality to convert "in situ"

Select column of dates then use

Data > Text to columns > Next > Next > under "column data format" choose "Date" > in dropdown select MDY > OK

Now you should have valid dates which you can reformat any way you want, e.g. dd/mm/yyyy

See [here](http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/521-tips-converting-text-dates-to-excel-dates-en-mase)

Comment: the dates are already valid. there's absolutely no reason to delineate this data...

Comment: Are you sure Brian? Alicia says the data is "text" - so the dates aren't recognised as dates by excel......which means that they can't simply be reformated - using Text to columns is a way to convert "text dates" to "true dates" - I copied the data from the question and used the method I suggested.....and I got true dates which can be re-formatted however one likes - did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I'm SURE.  If the cells were originally "text" format, then delineation the way you describe would leave 3 columns, that would then need to be merged before they could be reformatted, and all that is just an extended way of doing the `DATEVALUE` function that @chuff suggested. If data manipulation is needed to break out of a bad format, then that would be the best way to go, especially since it would require less user interaction.

Comment: No you don't have too split in to 3 columns you can just convert in situ as I say in my answer - see this link http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/521-tips-converting-text-dates-to-excel-dates-en-mase

Comment: Ok... I'll admit when I'm wrong. nice #protip.  Still would prefer the `datevalue` method a doubleclick as opposed to ttc, but still... nifty. Easier to record into a macro as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Excel's `DATEVALUE` function to convert each of the date strings to Excel date values, then format the cells as dates.

To format the cells, select them and right-click. Choose "Format cells" on the menu that appears, select Format Cells and choose a date format.

Comment: would you mind to share, how to use DATAVALUE function?

Comment: Sure. Enter as =DATEVALUE(date_as_string or reference_to_cell_containing_date_as_string).  For example, =DATEVALUE("Dec 3, 2012") or =DATEVALUE(A1) where cell A1 contains the value "Dec 3, 2012".

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work if the text contains a date in a format that is not your user default. I have my system (via Windows Control Panel) to use ISO 8601 (`yyyy-MM-dd`) by default, as a result `DATEVALUE` will not process dates in the `dd/MM/yyyy` format. So if you're using an `en-GB` computer (`dd/MM/yyyy`) you cannot get Excel to automatically parse `en-US` dates in the format `MM/dd/yyyy`) - while you can use `MID()` to split the string, it gets difficult if the format uses single-digit components instead of 2-digit components (e.g. `8/1/2016` instead of `08/01/2016`).

Comment: I really wish Excel would add a `DATEVALUE( text, format )` function so I could do things like `=DATEVALUE( "5/6/2016", "d/M/yyyy" )` - that would make things a LOT easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok to store date in format like 20120312 Then you can use below formula

```
=DATE(LEFT(C7;4);MID(C7;5;2);RIGHT(C7;2))
```

Please try below

```
=TEXT(A1;"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: I could not make it manually because I need to adjust 100 over date

Comment: Example, 
LEFT(C7;4)  

what does 4 refers to?

Comment: @AliciaGan 4 refers to number of characters from left so its 2012

Comment: she didn't ask for yyyddmm, she asked for dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @AshReva =TEXT(A1;"dd/mm/yyyy")
where do I place it?  was it on the data bar? 
whenever I try to click on the existing data column to convert it.  
for sure, the previous data will went missing

Comment: @AliciaGan do you know how to write formula? Where do you normally write it?

Answer (score 2):

Your dates are already in a format that Excel should be able to recognize (MMM DD, YYYY), but sometimes importing data can lead to the cells being formatted as Text.

Here's one way to fix your problem:

1. Type `0` into a cell and copy it. You may also copy a blank cell.

   [image]
2. Select all the dates in your range. **Right-click** the cells > **Paste Special** > **Add**.  Click **OK**.
   [image]

   Your dates should now look like these:

   [image]
3. With your dates still selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> (assuming you're on Windows) and then change the Number format to `mm/dd/yyyy`, `dd/mm/yyyy` or whichever you prefer.

   [image]

You can also try others ways to fix your dates, like:

- Copy the cells with the text dates and paste them into blank cells using **Paste Special** > **Add**.
- Highlight the cells with the dates, change the number format to `m/dd/yyyy` and then manually press `F2` for each cell. But this is too tedious.
- As [chuff mentioned above](https://superuser.com/a/564324/75569), use `DATEVALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

if you right click, you need to choose the format cells option, select the Custom option (all the way at the bottom), then in the Type box enter dd/mm/yyyy and click ok

Comment: To Brian , I can't find any (?) sign when I right click? 
where do I find format dropdown icon in excel? how does it look like?

TO jochn, I had click it but no changes 
What I had done 
 cell format -> custom -> dd//mm//yyyy

Comment: sorry, didn't see you put dd first, amended my answer

Comment: To Brian , I had exactly follow all the steps you mention. 
But , still remain the same .....no changes

Comment: For me it worked fine. I inserted a Date clicked the right mousbutton on this cell, cell format, custom and there in the bar to set a format "DD/MM/YYYY".

Comment: is there a possibility of our pc set some restriction for excel function?

Comment: No... but there is a possibility that using older version of excel will cause formatting issues and differences.  However, I'm fairly certain the custom date formatting was available at least back to the 97-03 .xls versions.  Could be wrong though...

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch I am extremely sorry for downvoting on wrong answer. It seems i cant revert it now. Really ashamed of this